# Is the following model parameterization identifiable?

Tags: self-study, identifiability

Let $X_i's$ be independent $i=1,2...n$ with $X_i\sim N(\mu+\alpha_i, \sigma^2)$ for each $i$. Let $\theta=(\alpha_1,...\alpha_p,\mu,\sigma)$ and $P_\theta$ be the joint pdf of the $X_i's$.

So, $P_\theta=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma})^n e^{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu-\alpha_i)^2}$

From what I understand, a model $P_\theta$ is identifiable if $\theta_1=\theta_2$ implies that $P_{\theta_1}=P_{\theta_2}$ and $\theta_1\not=\theta_2$ implies that $P_{\theta_1}\not=P_{\theta_2}$

Proof by counterexample:

Let $\theta_1=(\alpha_1,...\alpha_p,\mu,\sigma)$ and  $\theta_2=(\alpha_p,...\alpha_1,\mu,\sigma)$

$\theta_1\not=\theta_2 $ but $P_{\theta_1}=P_{\theta_2}$

So the model is unidentifiable?

Comment: It is not the case that $P_{\theta_1}=P_{\theta_2}$ (except if $\alpha_i=\alpha_{p+1-i}$ for $i=1, 2, \ldots, p$).

Comment: Consider some set of $\alpha$ and $\mu$ for $\theta_1$. Now in $\theta_2$ set its $\mu$, ($\mu_{(2)}$ say) to some particular value like $0$. Can you find a set of $\alpha_{(2),i}$ values that leave $E(W_i)$ unchanged?

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, I edited the $W_i$ to $X_i$ to match what I used in the joint pdf. Ok, I think that if either $\mu$ or $\sigma$ changes, then the resulting distribution will also be different. What I was thinking of was that since the $W_i's$ are similarly normally distributed with the difference being their respective $\alpha_i's$, then interchanging the order of the $\alpha_i's$ in $\theta$ will give me different $\theta's$ but the same $P_{\theta}$. For example, for $n=2$, $E[(x_1-\mu-\alpha_1)^2+(x_2-\mu-\alpha_2)^2]=E[(x_1-\mu-\alpha_2)^2+(x_2-\mu-\alpha_1)^2]$

Comment: In the left hand side,$x_1\sim N(\mu+\alpha_1.\sigma^2)$ and $x_2\sim N(\mu+\alpha_2.\sigma^2)$ while on the right, their distributions are switched.

Comment: @whuber Won't they be the same since the $X_i's$ are all $\sim N(\mu+\alpha_i,\sigma^2)$ and switching their parameters won't affect the expected value of their sums? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything in your post that refers to sums.  The $X_i$ are distinguishable.

Comment: Don't interchange order. In my example consider $p=2$. Let $\mu_{(2)}=0$ Let $\alpha_{(2),i}=\mu+\alpha_i$. Leave $\sigma$ as is.

Comment: It might help to draw a picture of the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ in the case $p=2$ (consider contouring its density, for instance). Its mean will be at $(\mu+\alpha_1, \mu+\alpha_2)$. The distribution with the $\alpha_i$ switched will *obviously* have a different mean when $\alpha_1\ne\alpha_2$.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Ok. My misunderstanding was that if you just interchanged some $\alpha_i's$, it will lead to the same joint pdf since you will just be adding them together as exponents.

Answer (score 2):

proof by counterexample
Let $\theta=(\alpha_1,...\alpha_p, \mu.\sigma)$ s.t. $\mu=-\alpha_i$ for all $i$.

This means that $P_{\theta}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma})^n e^{\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i)^2}$

But this $\theta$ is not unique. We can have an infinite number of $\theta$ such that $\mu=-\alpha_i$ for all $i$. All of them would have the same $P_{\theta}$. Thus, the model is not identifiable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with a question like this is to "tweak" one of the parameters and see if you can derive how you need to modify the other parameters to compensate and get back to where you started from.

For example, set $\mu' = \mu - \Delta$, for some real $\Delta$. Then:

$$\begin{align}
P_\theta&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\right)^n \exp\left({\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu-\alpha_i)^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\right)^n \exp\left({\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu' + \Delta-\alpha_i)^2}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\right)^n \exp\left({\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\mu' - \alpha'_i)^2}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

where $\alpha'_i = \alpha_i + \Delta$ for each $i$. That is, the distribution is the same for any parameter vector $(\alpha'_1,...,\alpha'_n,\mu',\sigma)=(\alpha_1 + \Delta, ..., \alpha_n + \Delta, \mu - \Delta, \sigma)$, no matter the value of $\Delta$, so the model is not identifiable.

This also shows you exactly where the symmetry is: the parameter $\mu$ defines a global reference level that you measure the $\alpha_i$ from, but it has no real meaning and you could raise it or lower it without any impact by compensating with the $\alpha_i$. You can simply set $\Delta = \mu$ and measure them from zero instead to get an identified model.